# Finding all subtrees of n-ary tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

I am trying to find all subtrees of n-ary tree. Only BFS or DFS does not work. Because the tree is not binary. For example:

```
        1
     /    \
    2      3
   / \    /|\
  4   6  5 7 8
        / \
       9   10
```

I want to show all subtrees including this one

```
        1
     /    \
    2      3
     \     |
      6    7
```

How can I extract this subtree from original one?

Comment: you should have in mind that the number of all subtrees in general is exponential. so if you call this on a big tree you are screwed.

Comment: BFS and DFS work for any graph. Whether the tree is binary or not doesn't matter at all

Comment: why do you need all subtrees? there is a chance your problem might be solved using different techinique

Comment: @svs Unfortunately my problem cannot be solved without all subtrees. I know it is exponetial.

Comment: @Paul BFS and DFS work of course for any graph. But they don't give us all subtrees.

Comment: Yes, they do. There is no difference in a BFS algorithm for binary and n-ary subtrees. It's the same idea.

Comment: @EmilVikström could you explain how could you print out tree that is shown above? BFS and DFS are searching algorithms not a tree splitting algorithms.

Comment: Can you do it for binary trees? What is fundamentally different for non-binary trees?

Comment: @n.m. The difference is that because the tree is not a binary so, if you want extract the three that is shown above using DFS, there is always 5 or 8 will be 7 in same level. You can not extract 7 without 5 or 8 using BFS or DFS.

Comment: I don't understand a word from your explanation. Please show your algorithm for binary trees, and point out the line that you cannot modify for non-binary trees.

Comment: @n.m. My question is simple. Could you show me BFS or DFS algorithm that gives you the tree is shown above? BFS or DFS cannot extract just middle nodes from n-ary tree.

Comment: Your claim is that you can do this for binary trees, but you cannot transform it into something that works for arbitrary trees. I can try and help you transform your algorithm if you show it and point out which step you cannot transform. I can also show you a ready algorithm in a few lines of Haskell, will it help? I'd like to try the first option first though. (I've also noticed that you are using the graph-theoretic definition of subtree, but it isn't clear whether you mean rooted subtrees or not; please clarify).

Answer (score 3):

To generate all (graph-theoretic) subtrees of a given tree, I will need some auxiliary notions.

A subtree is a connected subgraph pf a tree, or equivalently, a subgraph which is also a tree.

A descendant tree of a rooted tree is either the original rooted tree itself, or a rooted tree which is a child of one of its vertices. (Won't give an exact definition here as it should be clear from the notion of a tree as a recursive data structure).

A rooted subtree of a rooted tree is a subtree that has the same root as the original rooted tree. We can get a rooted subtree of a rooted tree by computing rooted subtrees of (some of) immediate children of the root, and combining those with the original root.

Note that an arbitrary subtree is a rooted subtree of a descendant tree.

I will deal with non-empty trees for simplicity.

```
-- a (rooted) tree is a root node and a list of children attached to it
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a] deriving Show
```

It is straightforward to get the descendants:

```
-- a descendant tree  is either a tree itself, 
-- or a descendant of a child of its root
descendants :: Tree a -> [Tree a]
descendants t@(Node a ts) = t : concatMap descendants ts
```

Rooted subtrees are not much harder:

```
-- to get a rooted subtree, take a root, choose which children to 
-- retain, take a rooted subtree of each retained child, 
-- and attach the results to a copy of the root

rootedSubtrees :: Tree a -> [Tree a]
rootedSubtrees (Node a ts) = [Node a tts | 
                              tts <- choices (map rootedSubtrees ts)]

-- this function receives a list of lists and generates all lists that 
-- contain 0 or 1 element from each input list
-- for ex. choices ["ab", "cd"] = ["","c","d","a","ac","ad","b","bc","bd"]
choices :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
choices [] = [[]]
choices (xs:xxs) = cs ++ [x:c | x <- xs, c <- cs] where cs = choices xxs
```

Finally, the list of arbitrary subtrees is

```
subtrees :: Tree a -> [Tree a]
subtrees t = concatMap rootedSubtrees (descendants t)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do the following.

- For each vertex in the tree you decide whether to cut the subtree with root the vertex or to keep exploring. Your number of choices is ~2^(number of nodes). Note it is note exactly 2^(number of nodes) (it's less but still exponential) since after you cut a subtree you don't explore it.
- For each configuration of choices for each vertex print the tree using `DFS`.

Your example is the configuration in which the subtree with roots `4`, `5`, `8`  were cut.

The cuts could be done implicitly by having flags for each node.